# TYPO3 10.4.36 Frontend Login doesn't find any user

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

After updating TYPO3 from 10.4.32 to 10.4.36, frontend login is not working anymore. We use a setup where the frontend users are stored on a separate storage folder. The pid of this folder is set as hidden value in the login form.

When using TYPO3 logging of the authentication class, it writes a `AuthenticationService: Login-attempt from username '*' not found!`.

Debugging the SQL query shows that it now ignores the `pid` value from the form and instead used a `pid IN (0)`, which explains the user not found message.

Searching through the source code shows a single place where the `checkPid_value` is set. In version 10.4.32 it was a simple assignment.

```
# FrontendUserAuthenticator::process (v10.4.32)
        $pid = $request->getParsedBody()['pid'] ?? $request->getQueryParams()['pid'] ?? 0;
        if ($pid) {
            $frontendUser->checkPid_value = implode(',', GeneralUtility::intExplode(',', $pid));
        }
```

In version 10.4.36 a lot more is happening, and the checkPid_value is not set in my case.

```
# FrontendUserAuthenticator::process (v10.4.36)
        $pidValue = (string)($request->getParsedBody()['pid'] ?? $request->getQueryParams()['pid'] ?? '');
        $pidParts = GeneralUtility::trimExplode('@', $pidValue, true, 2);
        $pid = $pidParts[0] ?? '';
        $givenHash = $pidParts[1] ?? '';
        $expectedHash = GeneralUtility::hmac($pid, FrontendUserAuthentication::class);

        // List of page IDs where to look for frontend user records
        if ($pid && (!$this->shallEnforceLoginSigning() || hash_equals($expectedHash, $givenHash))) {
            $frontendUser->checkPid_value = implode(',', GeneralUtility::intExplode(',', $pid));
        }
```

The source code suggests that the pid form value should now be somehow signed. I didn't find a description of how to sign the pid value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This change has been added with 10.4.33 to fix a security issue. this is described at [typo3.org](https://typo3.org/security/advisory/typo3-core-sa-2022-013).

If you set the pidlist manually, there are IMO 2 options:

1. disable the security feature:

Disable the check by disabling the feature `security.frontend.enforceLoginSigning` in the Install Tool. This should be avoided because then you are again affected by the security issue.

2. Sign the pidlist

Check out the code of TYPO3

```php
protected function getSignedStorageFolders(): string
    {
        $pidList = $this->getStorageFolders();
        return sprintf(
            '%s@%s',
            $pidList,
            GeneralUtility::hmac($pidList, FrontendUserAuthentication::class)
        );
    }
```

this could be used in your own setup as well

Comment: I used option 1 here, because i dont think it is an issue here, because we only have one storage folder for users. If someone manages to change the pid value it will only get no user.